# Excel - copy certain rows from worksheet in another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

I have found ways to solve this issue but I don't know how to tailor them to my specific problem. I've never written a marco or any VBA script before, so please be specific with your answers.

I have an Excel workbook with one worksheet named "foods", and four other worksheets named "snack choices", "breakfast choices", "lunch choices", and "dinner choices"

The heading in the "foods" worksheet looks like this:

**Food Amount Calories ... ETC ... Type**

Where "Type" contains "breakfast" "snack" "lunch" "dinner" or a combination of 2+ choices.

I'd like the entire row to copy to the corresponding "snack choices", "breakfast choices", "lunch choices", and "dinner choices" worksheet according to the value of the "Type" field in the "foods" worksheet.

For example, if I enter a new row into the "foods" worksheet with the "Type" field as "snack / breakfast" I'd like for the row to automatically appear in the "breakfast choices" and "snack choices" worksheets. (I could remove the slash or replace it with another character if that makes it easier)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `I've never written a marco or any VBA script before, so please be specific with your answers.` -> break down your needs into steps (write down your logic in English), then learn how to do each step in VBA, then put them altogether. Some VBA methods that will help are `For Each Next Loops`, `AutoFilter` (possibly), and `InStr`. If you develop some code and are stuck, please post it here. We can help much better if we have code to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main table with foods (Sheet 'Foods'):

[image: Main table with foods (Sheet 'Foods')]

Table for breakfasts:

[image: Table for breakfasts]

In this table:

A1: Type of food. In order to match combinations with other foods (Lunch/Cereal/Breakfast), it should start and end with '*': `*breakfast*` instead of `breakfast`. It's possible also to make a change in formulae.

Then we look for the first occasion of "breakfast" on the sheet 'Foods':

A3:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A$1,Foods!A:A;0)),"",MATCH($A$1,Foods!A:A,0))
```

As a result, a number of the matching row will be shown. If no match, a blank cell will be shown.

Then we match other data:

B2:

```
=IF(A3="","",INDIRECT("Foods!B"&$A3))
```

D2: change INDIRECT("Foods!B"&$A3)) to INDIRECT("Foods!D"&$A3)), E for E2 etc.

Other rows in column A below the first one (copied downwards from A4):

```
=IF(ISERROR(A3+MATCH($A$1,INDIRECT("Foods!A"&A3+1&":A60000"),0)),"",A3+MATCH($A$1,INDIRECT("Foods!A"&A3+1&":A60000"),0))
```

If no match, a blank cell will be shown.

I uploaded a spreadsheet  example to http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Type_of_food_on_another_sheet.xls

Comment: It seems that indexing efficiency for Excel 2003 diminishes (and volume increases) greatly if it has to deal with row numbers more than 16K. Unfortunately, I copied a formula down to the last row, and the volume  remained the same even after deleting all rows.  After sanitation the volume is 17 KB, shouldn't be a matter for dispute.

Comment: New Excel 2003 worksheet takes 11,5 KB simply by being an empty sheet.

Comment: Yes, I know :-) Waiting for upgrade from my employer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for excel formula to copy entire rows throughout many sheets to a single sheet.  The rows trying to copy have a "x" in the first column.

Ex.

Sheets are set up like this:

Columns
           1               2                      3                     4                      5
Rows 1    Sell           Priority                WHID                Sequence                 SAT
     2     X               1                       FG                  1.FG.01
     3                     1                       FG                  1.FG.01

Have many rows and many columns and many sheets.

Looking to get each 'X' in first column to pull to a new sheet.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have a different question, [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).